# 2D parallax with gyroscope/accelerometer avoiding z tilt

Tags: accelerometer, parallax, gyroscope

We are building an Unity game as a school project and we need to produce a parallax effect for different layers of gameObjects.

```
layer.transform.position = new Vector3(
    center - (Input.gyro.gravity.x * layerDistance)),
    layer.transform.position.y,
    layer.transform.position.z
) ;
```

Using both gyroscope X or accelerometer X this works quite right.
However we need to Z tilt in order to change the world's gravity. Therefor X tilt is influenced by Z tilt, so when we change the gravity (by rotating the device), the parallax is quite affected and mustn't change.

Would there be an algorithm or a sample code to solve this Z tilt effect ?